# Error message from Eventviewer for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, event-viewer

Recently i was using SQL Server 2008 which worked fine. But suddenly an error has appeared and my service gets automatically stopped even after i start it manually.

Service Name :- **MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS** 
Display Name :- **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)**

### Below is the error message i extracted from Eventviewer for SQL Server

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0x0002c6dc; actual: 0x6450282c). It occurred during a read of page (2:0) in database ID 3 at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: you run `DBCC CHECKDB(DB_NAME,REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)` to repair it..but there is a risk of data loss..better to take a backup before doing this. else go for `DBCC CHECKTABLE ('Table_name', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)`

Comment: @Sachu i searched that thread too but problem is that i cannot connect to the SQL Server as the service is down. now what should i do?

Comment: did u changed the windows login password or something recently? what is the error you are getting when try to start the service

Comment: @Sachu no error when i try to start it from "SQL configuration Manager" or "services.msc". Only thing that happens when i start the service is that it starts for a second and then goes offline.

Answer (score 2):

My Windows 7 SQLEXPRESS service was unable to start and application event log displayed problem with "modellog.ldf":

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
>   checksum (expected: 0xfd191356; actual: 0xfd1919fa). It occurred
>   during a read of page (2:0) in database ID 3 at offset
>   0000000000000000 in file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf'.

I found some interesting *template files* for model.mdf and modellog.ldf in folder

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Template Data\"

..and just made an overwrite of the problematic **model.mdf** and **modellog.ldf** in

> "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\"

And guess what? The service was able to start!

Found that all previous databases was still attached and "DBCC CHECKDB" executed ok for all databases for all databases using SQL Server Management Studio. master, model, all reported ok. Think all the transaction log files .ldf got new suffixes "_1.ldf".

Not sure if there are any other problems introduced with this undocumented fix but databases work as before.

Answer (score 0):

Data file can be repaired by DBCC repair command but there is risk of data loss so first take the database backup and also record all table count in excel file for compare the data after repair.

Step.1 Backup database.

Step.2 Get all tables record count.

Step.3 SET database in single user mode.

ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Step.4 RUN DBCC command-

DBCC CHECKDB(DB_NAME,REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

Step.5 Get again all tables record count and compare with old record count.

Hope this helps..

I done it for my problem it only lost one record from my previous data.

Comment: i searched that thread too but problem is that i cannot connect to the SQL Server as the service is down. now what should i do?

Comment: do you have any other idea in mind to solve this problem?

Comment: @DeveloperNation try this [link](http://ccm.net/forum/affich-35797-services-stops-automatically)

Comment: no it does not work. i even tried it manually starting the service in the way he asked us to.

Comment: @DeveloperNation do u have the backup of the database?

Comment: no i don't and btw "modellog.ldf" is not my database it is created by default when the SQL server is installed my log file is "Project_1.log"

Comment: @DeveloperNation Ok hope this can help you [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/) in this link 3rd point is corrupted model database

Comment: @DeveloperNation is this sorted out?

Comment: nope the link had me half way but then got stuck so i formatted my PC again and now will have to work on everything again

Comment: @DeveloperNation oh..so u will lose your data?

Answer (score 0):

Installing 'SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 2' solved my problem.